# angular2 Can't have multiple template bindings on one element

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this angular2 template:

```
<template *ngIf="alerts.length > 0">
<alert *ngFor="let alert of alerts;let i = index" [type]="alert.type" dismissible="true" (close)="closeAlert(i)">
  {{ alert?.msg }}
</alert>
  </template>
```

I get these errors:

```
zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute named 'template' or prefixed with * (" </div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="false" class="container p-t-10">
    <alert *ngIf="alerts.length > 0" [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let alert of alerts;let i = index" [type]="alert.type" dismissible="true" (close)="closeAlert"): b@5:37
```

what's the problem I put *ngIf and *ngFor in defferent html elements. It should work. no?

and:

```
Can't bind to 'type' since it isn't a known property of 'alert'. (""container p-t-10">
    <alert *ngIf="alerts.length > 0" *ngFor="let alert of alerts;let i = index" [ERROR ->][type]="alert.type" dismissible="true" (close)="closeAlert(i)">
      {{ alert?.msg }}
    </alert>
"): b@5:80
```

I added the

`*ngIf="alerts.length > 0` to avoid cases of `alert = []`. How can i fix it otherwise?

Comment: try with `attr.type` instead of type simple

Answer (score 17):

The `*` in `*ngFor` makes Angular to add a `<template>` tag. On a `<template>` tag this doesn't make sense and therefore here structural directives have a different syntax.

```
<template ngFor [ngForOf]="alerts" let-alert let-i="index">
```

Because different syntax for almost the same on different places caused quite some confusion, the Angular team recently introduced

```
<ng-container>
```

that behaves similar to the `<template>` tag (is not added to the DOM) but allows the more common syntax

```
<ng-container *ngIf="alerts.length > 0">
  <alert *ngFor="let alert of alerts;let i = index" [type]="alert.type" dismissible="true" (close)="closeAlert(i)">
    {{ alert?.msg }}
  </alert>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: this empty array check will fix also the `Can't bind to 'type' since it isn't a known property of 'alert'` ?

Comment: still get this error:

`Can't bind to 'type' since it isn't a known property of 'alert'. ("
    <ng-container *ngIf="alerts.length > 0">
    <alert *ngFor="let alert of alerts;let i = index" [ERROR ->][type]="alert.type" dismissible="true" (close)="closeAlert(i)">
      {{ alert?.msg }}
    </alert>
"): b@6:54`

Comment: You are probably missing an import or a declaration in `@NgModule({imports: [ModuleThatContainsAlert], declaration: [AlertComponent])` depending on where `<alert>` comes from. The error message indicates that there is no `AlertComponent` instantiated for this element.

Comment: `public alerts:Array<Object> = [];` is the member. I thought the error is because the array it empty at the beginning. thought the *ngIf should fix this

Comment: It's because `<alert [type]=xxx` because `<alert>` has no property `type`.

Comment: it's added dynamically when needed ` callErrorAlert(error) {
    this.alerts.push({msg: (error) ? error : 'save is failed', type: 'danger', closable: true});
  }`

Comment: Properties are not added dynamically. Properties are added to HTML by default like `disabled` or `value` for `<input>`s but that's a fixed set or when Angular2 components or directives are created on an element (`@Input() type:string;`). If this is not the case you perhaps mean an attribute instead of a property. In this case use `<alert [attr.type]="xxx">`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<ng-container>` for this case. As a example:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="totalItems > 0">
      <tr *ngFor="let item of outputs| paginate: { id:'ab', itemsPerPage: pageSize, currentPage: currentPage, totalItems: totalItems  }; let $index = index">
        <td>{{item.x}}</td>
        <td>{{item.y | date: 'MMMM d, y, h:mm:ss a' }}</td>
        <td>{{item.z}}</td>
        <td>{{item.r}}</td>

      </tr>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="totalItems > 10">
      <tr *ngFor="let item of outputs| paginate: { id:'aabbbbbbbbb', itemsPerPage: pageSize, currentPage: currentPage, totalItems: totalItems  }; let $index = index">
            <td>{{item.x}}</td>
        <td>{{item.y | date: 'MMMM d, y, h:mm:ss a' }}</td>
        <td>{{item.z}}</td>
        <td>{{item.r}}</td>
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
```